# Custom image sizes ignored in WP 3.5

Tags: customization, uploads, images

Since migrating to WP 3.5 I discovered that my custom image sizes get ignored  - whenever I try and output one of them WP just defaults to the original image instead. Kind of frustrating... Any idea where to start?

functions.php -

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); 
add_image_size( 's', 145, 999 );
add_image_size( 'm', 300, 999 );
add_image_size( 'l', 455, 999 );
add_image_size( 'tablet', 1024, 9999 );
add_image_size( 'browser', 1920, 9999 );
```

The original media sizes in WP admin is set to 0x0. Also tried reseting these in case WP chose to disable image sizes altogether for some reason.

index.php -

```
// Inside the loop
$size = 's';
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_field('thumbnail'), $size);
echo $image[0];
```

The field 'thumbnail' is a custom field I've created. It stores the ID of the attachment.

Edit: This seems to be a bug
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22985

Comment: the bug u attached is marked fixed.
Whats inside this? get_field('thumbnail') - can u print it?

are u sure ur getting an id?

Answer (score 0):

Try regenerating images for each sizes by using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/).

Comment: I've actually tried both that one and the "Ajax regenerate thumbnails" plugin already. No errors, but I suspect the sizes are "unsynced" with the original attachment.